# code involving indexPath & NSIndexPath works - but why is it redundant?

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I'm getting back to using CloudKit and in the project I'm revisiting, I have a query fetch performed and I am left with an array of CKRecords. I'm setting this array to be displayed via TableController.  Anyways, I have this one line of code (which works)... but I am just unsure why I am setting the indexPath as NSIndexPath.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dining") as! table1cell
    let restaurant: CKRecord = categories[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.Name.text = restaurant.value(forKey: "Name") as? String

    return cell
```

With my other non-CKRecord TableController projects, I know I don't have to set the indexPath to itself, in essence.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Provide some context. Where is this line of code? Show how `indexPath` is declared.

Comment: Also clarify whether you are using Swift 2 or 3.

Comment: Unrelated: Standard naming conventions dictate that classnames should start with uppercase letters and method and variable names start with lowercase letters. You have the opposite in several places in the code you posted in your question.

Comment: why dont you upvote the accepted answer? this user took his time to help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the cast to `NSIndexPath` is pointless. Simply change the line to:

```
let restaurant: CKRecord = categories[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

If indexPath is not stored in an explicitly typed var, you probably casted it to avoid a compiler message. If the compiler does not know indexPath is of type NSIndexPath, accessing the .row property would likely cause an error.

Where are you declaring/storing indexPath? What happens when you remove the as NSIndexPath cast?

Edit: re-reading your question, I believe the answer is:

"You are not storing indexPath as itself, you are casting whatever is stored in indexPath to be of type NSIndexPath"